# Using grep to return two instances from a list of options in the same line

Tags: bash, grep

I have some data in the format

```
abc,def
```

where abc and def are domain names that link to each other.

I have a list of these domains that I'm interested in (abc, def, and ghi), and need to find instances where any two on my list are mentioned together. That is to return:

```
abc,def
def,abc
abc,ghi
...
```

But not

```
abc,xyz
```

I also need to return:

```
abc,abc  
def,def (which do occur)
```

I tried using:

```
grep -e 'abc\|def\|ghi' filename.csv | grep -e 'abc\|def\|ghi'
```

but this fails, presumably because I'm committing some logical absurdity, but I can't see what it is.

I'm writing a .sh script to use in Gitbash for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like

```
grep -E "([,]?(abc|def|ghi)){2}"
```

should work. You can extend [,] to cover whitespace or any other garbage you have around.

This line will look for 2 occurences of things mentioned inside brackets, which is optional comma before and then one of your list of interesting keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to store the names you want to see in columns and then check if all the columns match any of them:

```
awk -F, -v patt="abc def ghi" 
    'BEGIN {
        split(patt,names," ");                    # store data in array
        for (i in names) n[names[i]]=names[i]     # store in indexes
     } 
     ($1 in n) && ($2 in n) ' file                # check if present
```

See it in action:

```
$ cat a
abc,def
def,abc
abc,ghi
abc,abc
abc,xyz
xyz,123
$ awk -F, -v patt="abc def ghi" 'BEGIN {split(patt,names," "); for (i in names) n[names[i]]=names[i]} ($1 in n) && ($2 in n) ' a
abc,def
def,abc
abc,ghi
abc,abc
```

Comment: Many thanks!  As my list is quite short, the solution from @artur-biesiadowski works well enough, but I would take your approach if I had a longer list